# Run the application at startup in linux

Tags: linux, process, startup

I am making a Linux application. This application synchronizes the client's files and folders with cloud. There is folder in **home** directory in which all the files from cloud will be synchronized. I want that the application should be **started in background** **after boot** and work in background automatically. 
How can I do it?

Comment: Started in background for which user?

Comment: For that user who installs the application.

Comment: A regular user normaly cannot install any applications. Even if a normal user can run a graphical installer, it nearly always does its job as a superuser behind the scenes, and has no idea which user has started up the GUI.

Comment: After one and a half year you still have to choose the right answer to your question.

Answer (score 3):

If you have systemd you can create a service as shown [here](https://home-assistant.io/docs/autostart/systemd/).

Otherwise you have to use [init](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56957/how-to-start-an-application-automatically-on-boot).

Answer (score -1):

If you have what is essentially a single-user system, you can use `init`/`systemd` to start background processes as a nominated, unprivileged user. However, that isn't the usual use of these techniques.

In a multi-user, graphical system, you probably want user-related background processes to start when the user's desktop session starts. Not only is this (usually) the proper timing for such operations, it allows multiple users to be supported.

The various graphical desktops available for Linux all provide slightly different ways to run user applications at login. It's probably impossible to find a method that will work for all desktops. For full coverage, you probably need to implement something that detects what desktop is in use, and uses the method appropriate to that desktop.

However, many desktops respect the use of `$HOME/.config/autostart/`. Files in that directory should have a .desktop extension, and be of the same format as application launchers. For example:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=MyThingie
GenericName=foo
Comment=foo
Exec=/path/to/my/executable
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=foo
Categories=Network;FileTransfer;
StartupNotify=false
```